# Permalinks not working when using a custom query for a custom post type

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I'm using WP_query to get a list of items from a custom post type. My code is as follows:

```
<?php
  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => array('recepten'), 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'paged'=>$paged ));
```

If I set my permalink settings to standard, I can view the second page with posts here: /?page_id=8&paged=2 , but when I've set my permalink settings to "Post name", this page gives me a 404: /recepten/page/2/

It also might be worth noting that I'm trying to use the Pagenavi plugin to get the pagination to work (since I can't seem to get it working without a plugin). Though I think the urls should also be working without using the plugin.

Thanks in advance!

Extra (less relevant) question: Is it possible to change the url from /recepten/page/2 to /recepten/2 ?

Edit: I solved the issue. The problem was that the name of the post type was the same as the slug of the page that contained the query. Changing the name of the post type solved it.

Comment: See this link to solve problem https://wordpress.org/support/topic/permalinks-404-with-custom-post-type

Answer (score 1):

use custom permalink structure
https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: I have been dealing with this issue for weeks. Without permalinks the post wouldn't show and then I put it on the Post Name option in permalinks and that still didn't do anything. As soon as I used the Custom with the /%postname%/ in it. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

There may be several issues these solutions may resolve it:

1. **.htaccess** file in your wordpress root folder has write issue or rewrite module is not enabled:

   1.1. change permission chmod 666 **.htaccess** and then change permalinks settings and save it to see permalinks  updated. Open **.htaccess** file to see the content as:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]<br>
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f<br>
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d<br>
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]<br>
   </IfModule>
   ```

Now revert the file permission back to 644 and refresh page to see the link.

1.2. **sudo a2enmod rewrite** and then **sudo systemctl restart apache2** and check the link now.

2. Edit edit  **/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf** if you have not configured virtual host and add the higlighted one in

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/html/wordpress directory>
   **AllowOverride All**<br>
   **Require all granted**
   </Directory>
   ```
3. If you have configured virtual host you need to edit /etc/apache2/sites-available/you-configuration-filename.conf and add the higlighted one in

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/html/wordpress directory>
   **AllowOverride All**<br>
   **Require all granted**
   </Directory>
   ```

   Restart you apache server

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart apache2
   ```